# mediaRecorder java.langRuntimeException stop failed - recording audio

Tags: java, android, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying to record audio, and it needs to be high quality.

This code is working fine on a lot of devices, however on some devices like the galaxy s4 mini, moto G, and even the Galaxy s4 and HTC one mini, it will not work.

Here is my recording method

```
public class RecordingHandler {

    private static MediaRecorder recorder;

    static void beginRecording(String output) throws Exception {

        ditchMediaRecorder();
        File outFile = new File(output);
        if (outFile.exists())
            outFile.delete();
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.getAudioSourceMax());
        recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
        recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
        recorder.setOutputFile(output);
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }

    static void ditchMediaRecorder() {
        // if we have the recorder, release it
        if (recorder != null)
            recorder.release();
    }

    static void stopRecording() {
        if (recorder != null) {

            try {
                recorder.stop();
            } catch (RuntimeException stopException) {
                // handle cleanup here
                Log.d("Recording Handler", "Runtime Exception");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The error I'm getting

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
at com.appulse.beatbox.RecordingHandler.stopRecording(RecordingHandler.java:34)
at com.appulse.beatbox.SoundRecord$5.onTouch(SoundRecord.java:347)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7784)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2169)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1613)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2539)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2117)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8005)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4300)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4179)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3714)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3764)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3733)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3741)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3901)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3714)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3764)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3733)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3741)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3714)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5973)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5946)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5909)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6057)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:214)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:134)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Note that a RuntimeException is intentionally thrown to the application, if no valid audio/video data has been received when stop() is called. This happens if stop() is called immediately after start(). May be on low end devices you need to set different bitrate ,sample rate etc.

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder, hi, having same issue now. What do you mean by no valid audio/video data received? I use a Galaxy Note 8 as my testing device, do I have to set something specifically for it to work?